# Rails - session variable lost between controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**Edit - I misunderstood the exact nature of the problem, have reposted here with a better grasp of the issue: [Rails / Devise - updating session variables between controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501992/rails-devise-updating-session-variables-between-controller-actions)**

I am using a session variable to pass data between three form submission controller actions in my Rails app, but I am having an issue where the process works the first time I run through but fails the second time because the session variable does not pass to a subsequent controller action - however, if I clear my browser history, it works fine (but will fail if I try to repeat without clearing history, etc.). The app uses Devise for user log in, and the problem seems to be related to the session being destroyed on log out.

The session variable in question here is `session[:ids]`, and it seems that it is not being passed from the `submission` action to the `approval` action without first clearing the browser history.

Here are the routes:

```
post 'report/submission'
get 'report/approval'
get 'report/summary' => 'report#summary'
```

And the associated controller actions (added a few groups of `puts` to check the variable values in the console):

```
def submission
    @incomingReport = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:report])

    @newReportIDArray = Array.new

    @incomingReport.each do |x|
        #DATA PROCESSING STUFF HERE
        @newReportIDArray.push(@new_report.id)
    end

    session[:ids] = @newReportIDArray

    puts "submission_marker"
    puts @newReportIDArray
    puts "submission_marker_end"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: {
          success: 200
        }.to_json
      end
    end
end

#USER LOGIN OCCURS HERE
def approval
    @reportIDs = session[:ids]

    puts "approval_marker"
    puts @reportIDs
    puts "approval_marker_end"

    @reportIDs.each do |x|
        @new_report = Report.find(x)
        @new_report.user_id = current_user.id
        @new_report.save
    end

    redirect_to report_summary_path
end


def summary
    @reportIDs = session[:ids]

    puts "summary_marker"
    puts @reportIDs
    puts "summary_marker_end"
end
#USER LOGS OUT AFTER SUMMARY
```

So if I run this with clean history, my console looks like this:

```
submission_marker
766
submission_marker_end

approval_marker
766
approval_marker_end

summary_marker
766
summary_marker_end
```

but if I log out after the first `summary` and then I try to run through the process without clearing the history, I end up with

```
submission_marker
767
submission_marker_end

approval_marker

approval_marker_end
```

and the error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`, referring to `@reportIDs.each` in the `approval` action.

What am I missing here? Why is it that with a clean history, everything runs ok, but with a 'dirty' history, the session variable sets for the `submission` action but is dropped by/on its way to the `approval` action?  I see that this has something to do with Devise and the destruction of the session, but I don't understand why I can't create a new session variable.